# Set default alarm app such that Siri alarm request is made in that app

Tags: iphone, siri, alarm

How can I tell iphone OS to use a specific alarm clock app instead of default Clock app to for verbal request of 'set an alarm for 13:30'?

(because default 9 minute snooze that can not be changed is not user friendly).

On android, such setting is possible and voice assistant routes the request to the app specified.

(are certain alarm apps more linked with Siri than others?) (e.g., I hope to use Alarm Clock For Me') but the question is generic for any alarm app).

Comment: Does your preferred app plug into Siri and shortcuts? If it does, you should be able to set up automations to your liking.

Comment: Can you provide guidance how can I find out if app supports formulation of shortcuts. I can't believe I am the first to request Siri to do app specific tasks for any app.

Comment: Sure - When you open shortcuts, tap on the gallery - then see if the app is showing up. When you install the app it registers all actions with the shortcut app. Or you can ask the vendor of that app directly. You can also just try to make some installed app respond to the “set an alarm” and see if it activates correctly